# Don't understand a assignment in school. Need clarifacation

Tags: excel

So I got this question that I have to make combo chart that has a histogram with relative frequency of some grades that I already made and a line chart of the bellcurve of the normal distibution from N(6.5; 1.5). What does this N(6.5; 1.5) mean? I don't really understand the question.

Gr,
A student

Comment: A normal distribution with mean 6.5 and standard deviation of 1.5

Comment: Ahhh okay, they could have just said it like you would be a bit more clear